# Ionic 2 , cordova-plugin-geolocation not work in android 7.0 and higher

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, geolocation

Cordova plugin geolocation does not support android 7.0 and higher

How can i get geolocation in IONIC 2 for android 7 and higher

Answer (score 0):

try https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/ 
 there are tons of tutorials. just search.. :)